# network-manager-openconnect certificate verification failure

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

This issue has been around for a while and I haven't been able to find any solution for it. It's present in Ubuntu 18.04, and I had the same issue in 16.04.

When establishing a VPN connection with `network-manager-openconnect`, the following errors are logged in syslog:

```
Jun 25 09:27:00 redacted openconnect[18890]: Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
```

The issue here is that the connection is being made to the VPN server's IP address, rather than it's DNS name. This causes a certificate verification errors. It looks like as a compensation to this, the server certificate hash is supplied, however this causes another, different error. This is despite the fact that in the VPN configuration, the hostname and not the IP address is specified.

Is there a way to force Network Manager to call openconnect via hostname instead of IP address?

Looking at the command that is run by NetworkManager:

```
$ ps aux | grep openconnect
/usr/sbin/openconnect --servercert sha256:<hash> --syslog --cookie-on-stdin --script /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-openconnect-service-openconnect-helper --interface vpn0 <ip>:443
```

To demonstrate the certificate errors, run the command manually, without the --servercert parameter:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openconnect <ip>:443 --authenticate
POST https://<ip>/
Connected to <ip>:443
SSL negotiation with <ip>
Server certificate verify failed: certificate does not match hostname
Certificate from VPN server "<ip>" failed verification.
Reason: certificate does not match hostname
To trust this server in future, perhaps add this to your command line:
   --servercert sha256:<hash>
Enter 'yes' to accept, 'no' to abort; anything else to view: 
Note the certificate verification failure.
```

Now using the hostname instead of the IP - everything is fine:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openconnect <hostname>:443 --authenticate
POST https://<hostname>/
Connected to <ip>:443
SSL negotiation with <hostname>
Connected to HTTPS on <hostname>
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
No certificate errors.
```

Now, using the IP with the servercert parameter:

```
$ /usr/sbin/openconnect <ip>:443 --authenticate --servercert sha256:<hash>
POST https://<ip>/
Connected to <ip>:443
SSL negotiation with <ip>
Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Connected to HTTPS on <ip>
XML POST enabled
Please enter your username and password.
```

Compare the error to the first example - it's a different error. This one fails because the signer is not found. Considering that we're just specifying a hash, I guess that makes sense, as there's not trust chain to follow.

Why is network manager calling openconnect with the IP instead of the hostname? Can it be forced to use the hostname? Is this actually a bug in NetworkManager?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use the standard OpenVPN port(s) instead of port 443?

Comment: I'm using openconnect (cisco anyconnect) not OpenVPN, so it is the standard port (and it is a production VPN so changing ports isn't an option)